# How to avoid the default line break between declare and class when formatting?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, tslint

I'm using palantir/tslint for TypeScript linting and got a tslint.json config file that is being used in my IntelliJ IDE for code formatting. Whenever I format (ctrl+alt+L) the TypeScript code, it introduces a line-break between `declare` and `class` (or `let`).

I'd like to know how to override the default line break?

After formatting:

[image]

Comment: can't recreate. What Idea version do you use? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15917 was fixed as far back as Idea 15

Comment: @lena IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.2

Comment: I see:) Please try upgrading Idea then. BTW, Idea 2017.1 that is coming soon will support importing code style preferences from tslint.json. And TypeScript support there is much-much better than in 14